# How to return a list of integers that count total number of strings in a list of list of list of strings that satisfy a given condition?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get a list of integers that return the number of strings in a list of list of list of strings which is not alphabet.
e.g:

```
count_number([[['B0', 'N1','C']], [['AT', '1', 'K']]])
```

This should give me a result of

```
[2,1]
```

What I tried is below: I've only managed to get the total number of strings in the whole list.

```
count = 0
    for sublist in List1:
        for words in sublist:
            for item in words:
                if not item.isalpha():
                    count +=1
return count
```

How to turn this into a list of int? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: for this case `[[['B01', 'N1','C1'], ['B01', 'N1','C1']], [['AT1', '1', 'K']]]` the expected  result should be : `[4, 4, 2]` ?

Comment: No,it should be [3,3,2]because I just want the number of strings in each sublist which is not alphabet, I am not counting the total number of digits here:)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regular expression:

```
import re

l = [[['B0', 'N1','C']], [['AT', '1', 'K']]]

[sum(bool(re.search('[^a-zA-Z]', w)) for w in e) for i in l for e in i]
```

output:

```
[2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```
def count_number(List1):
    out_put_list = []
    for sublist in List1:
        for words in sublist:
            count = 0
            for item in words:
                if not item.isalpha():
                    count +=1
            out_put_list.append(count)
    return out_put_list


print(count_number([[['B01', 'N1','C1'], ['B01', 'N1','C1']], [['AT1', '1', 'K']]]))
```

Output:

```
[3, 3, 2]
```